# Disqus marks my previous wordpress comments as posted by an anonymous guest

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

I own a 8 years old blog, to which I have posted a fair amount of blog posts AND comments.

Yesterday, I just installed Disqus. 
It seems to work just fine : I managed to export my old comments to Disqus, so it displays them the way it should...

**... EXCEPT THAT it won't recognize my old comments** (comments that I posted before I installed Disqus) **as my own** : my old comments are marked as posted by an anonymous guest, eventhough my Wordpress (admin) user email is the same as the one I use for my Disqus profile (which is odd, because one would expect that Disqus is able to identify my comments).

Is there anything I can do to get Disqus to recognize my previous comments and to re-attribute them to my Disqus profile ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your Disqus profile there is an option called "Merging"

It will tie all your previous WordPress comments to your Disqus account, providing you are using the same email address.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I never accepted and thanked you for that. It was, indeed, the solution. thank you.